# How do I group a set of entities (people) into 10 equal portions but based on their usage for EX using Oracle's Toad 11g (SQL)

Tags: sql

Hi I have a list of 2+ mil people and their usage put in order from largest to smallest.

I tried ranking using row_number () over (partition by **user column** order by **usage** desc) as rnk

but that didnt work ..the results were crazy.

Simply put, I just want 10 equal groups of 10 with the first group consisting of the highest usage in the order of which i had first listed them.

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ntile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions101.htm):

```
select t.*, ntile(10) over (order by usage desc) as usage_decile
from t;
```

The only caveat:  This will divide the data into exactly 10 equal sized groups.  If usage values have duplicates, then users with the same usage will be in different deciles.

If you don't want that behavior, use a more manual calculation:

```
select t.*,
       ceil(rank() over (order by usage desc) * 10 /
            count(*) over ()
           ) as usage_decile
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Part a worked as I wanted perfectly. I'll save the other for a later when i need it to be more detailed! Thank you!